# Save results from stored procedure into new permanent table every time it runs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to write a stored procedure that stores the results into a new permanent table every time it runs. This is the code I have so far but I am unsure how to alter the code to save into a new table everytime.

Stored Procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spquarterresults]
(
    @quarter VARCHAR(1)
    ,@year VARCHAR (5)
)

AS

BEGIN

Drop table if exists #tmp_edseverity

CREATE TABLE #df1
    (PERIOD VARCHAR(7),
    FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    LastName VARCHAR(25),
    )

INSERT INTO #df1
            (
                TimePeriod,
                FirstName,
                LastName
            )
            SELECT distinct
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, Year) + ' Q' + TRIM(CONVERT(CHAR, Quarter)) AS TimePeriod,
            Participant_FirstName as FirstName,
            Participant_LastName as LastName
            FROM dbo.dfinfo
            WHERE Year = @year and Quarter = @quarter

END
```

What I would like is for the results of #df1 to be stored in a table called dbo.q1results. When I run it next I would like it to save in dbo.q2results. How can I alter the below code above and the current execute statement (below) that I am running.
Execute Statement:

```
EXECUTE dbo.spquarterresults
@year = '2022',
@quarter = '1';
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest. Why do you need to create so many *identical* tables?

Comment: Why not have a single table with columns for the Year/Quarter (which look like numbers to me, not strings?

Comment: Basically, this code will be run 4 times a year (once every quarter). The code can all be saved into the same table for one year but we would like a new table for the next year. Just trying to see if there is an easy way to change the table name in the execute function.

for example 2022 will have q1 to q4 data. then once 2023 starts, the data will need to be saved in a new table.

Comment: I am relatively new to sql so if this is not a good solution, I completely understand!

Comment: No, it's not a good solution. As mentioned, instead you should have one table, and then you can have a `Year` and `Quarter` column.

Comment: Okay, i'll looking into doing that, thank you! @Larnu